# Painting Trex composite deck board

Tags: paint, decking, trex

I just got done re-painting my porch. In the process, I noticed that one of the wooden deck boards was rotten, so I pulled it off, and now I have to replace it. I happen to have some extra Trex boards from a previous project, so I was thinking of using one of those and painting it to match the rest of the porch. But apparently the manufacturer doesn't recommend this, and they say it'll void the warranty. (Older Trex boards can be painted, but this doesn't apply here.)

If I paint it anyway, what'll happen? I'd prefer to use the Trex board since I already have it, and there's a good chance it'll still last longer than wood. Is there anything I need to be aware of? Do these new Trex boards explode when exposed to paint, or something like that?

Comment: I would imagine the newer trex covering does not take paint well, the paint will not bond to it without heavy duty sanding.

Comment: Is the Trex the same thickness as the other boards?

Answer (score 2):

Paint simply doesn't bond to plastic very well without considerable prep-work and specialty paint. You would experience ugly peeling after just 1-2 years. Trex is specifically engineered to withstand foot traffic; it will absolutely resist being painted.

You have 3 options:

- Replace the rotted wood boards with new wood
- Replace the entire deck with Trex boards
- Replace the rotted wood boards with Trex and learn to live with it